# KivEnt installation: Fatal error LNK1181 can't open input file 'glew32.lib'

Tags: python, visual-studio, kivy, fatal-error, glew

It's been long since I wanted to try KivEnt and I'm finally doing the installation.

I want to install all the KivEnt modules (core, cymunk...) by running the `setup.py`, but I have this issue with the first one (core):

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\share\kivent\modules\core>python setup.py install[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Me\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-11-17_62.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
Using distutils
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'kivent_core.entity' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics -IC:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\tools\gles_compat -IC:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\include -IC:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tckivent_core/entity.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\kivent_core/entity.obj -std=gnu99 -ffast-math
cl : Ligne de commande warning D9002 : option '-std=gnu99' unknown ignored
cl : Ligne de commande warning D9002 : option '-ffast-math' unknown ignored
entity.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\um\x86" opengl32.lib glu32.lib glew32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_entity build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\kivent_core/entity.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.7\kivent_core\entity.cp37-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\kivent_core\entity.cp37-win32.lib
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'glew32.lib'
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

I have been searching for more than 5 hours on this error and I still don't find something that correct the problem. I saw it could be a problem of dependencies but I'm new to those concepts and I don't really get the point of this, and even don't know what to do to make this work. Although I tried to add manually the files into the right folders but I get lost in the end.

I'd be extremely grateful for getting help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found out the problem. The only thing was to move the file `glew32.lib` in one of the right directories (in my case this is the first one checked in the error message).